# mercurial: excluding .hg files with archive

Tags: mercurial, archive

I am running:

```
hg archive --exclude .hg ../rdiff-backup-fs-1.0.0b3
```

trying to export files for a package without adding .hg files. I get:

```
abort: path contains illegal component: .hg
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to exclude files `.hgtags` and `.hg_archival.txt`.

**EDIT**
OK, I'm an idiot. You need to specify the whole pattern, not just the prefix.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your own question you should add it and pick it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `-X` requires full name, rather than only a prefix. Therefore I had to use `-X .hgtags`.

Comment: You should have used

`hg archive --exclude ".hg*" this that`

Answer (score 3):

`hg archive` already excludes the .hg directory (in fact, that's kind of the whole point, no?), there's no need to specify it.

Comment: He didn't mean the .hg directory he meant the .hgtags and .hgarchive file.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set default patterns to ignore when exporting and avoid too many typing.

Put this on your `.hgrc`

```
[defaults]
archive = -X .hgtags -X .hgignore -X .todo
```

This way you can do `hg archive ~/project.tgz` and those files will be always omitted.